# Eclipse JDT AST: check if SimpleName is a variable identifier

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to list all variables used in an Expression node. I've created a visitor to SimpleName node but this captures all identifiers like function calls, class names etc. How do I check if a SimpleName node is identifier of a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type binding of the node gives this information

example for variable:

```java
SimpleName simpleName = //initialize variable;
if (simpleName.resolveBinding() instanceof VariableBinding){
    // simpleName is a variable identifier
}
if (simpleName.resolveBinding() instanceof MethodBinding){
    // simpleName is a method identifier
}
```